# How to handle variables that is null in JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

In my JSON file there is an array (rents). In this array there is a varible, serial, which can be null or a string. I loop throug my array (rents) if the serial variable is null i want to continue the loop, but when is it not null i want to save it. But somehow it does not behave like that. The array stop looping when it comes to get "serial".

Here is my code:

```
    public static string sendRequest(string url, string method) {
            try
            {
                // Set reqiued information for api
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(main_url + url);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Current_Access_Token);
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json;v=1";
                httpWebRequest.Method = method;

                // Get adn return responses
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                string respStr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                return respStr;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No responses");
            }
            return "";
        }


public static void GetRentGames()
        {
            string resp = sendRequest("api.php/currentCustomer/rents", "GET");
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(resp);
            JArray Juser = (JArray)jObject["response"]["data"]["rents"];
            //Console.WriteLine(resp);
            foreach(var i in Juser)
            {
                var matchGame = ApiConnector.rentGame.Find(x => x.name == i["item"]["name"].ToString());

                if(matchGame == null)
                {
                    //name and id works just fine. it is the serial i can't get, and I think because the serial is null?
                    Console.WriteLine(i["serial"].ToString());
                    var Game = new RentGame(i["item"]["name"].ToString(), i["id"].ToString(), i["serial"].ToString());
                    rentGame.Add(Game);
                    Console.WriteLine("Add rent game " + Game.name);
                }

            }

        }
```

JSON file- first index:

```
"response":{
        "code":200,
        "status":"success",
        "data":{
            "rents":[
                {
                    "id":"34414",
                    "start_date":"2015-12-08",
                    "download_url":null,
                    "serial":null, ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The array stop looping when it comes to get serial."  Do you mean it throws an exception?  If so, please post the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the value is null, do this:

```
            if(matchGame == null)
            {
                // Only do this if the serial is not null
                if (i["serial"].Type != JTokenType.Null)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(i["serial"].ToString());
                   var Game = new RentGame(i["item"]["name"].ToString(), i["id"].ToString(), i["serial"].ToString());
                   rentGame.Add(Game);
                   Console.WriteLine("Add rent game " + Game.name);
            }
```

The difficulty is that the JSON parser does not convert null objects in JSON to null objects in C#.  (why??!?)  Instead, it makes it a JToken object, with a "Type" of "Null".

You can see this in the debugger window like this:
[image: Screen shot of Visual Studio 2015 watch window]
The "Value" column shows as {} which doesn't mean much to me.  The "Type" column shows that it is a JToken object.  So what is a JToken?  Well, if you expand, you see it has lots of properties: Next, Last, Parent, Path, ... Okay, so that explains why they didn't make it a real null.  They want to track all these other things.  It looks like you could use the "HasValues" property or the "Type" property to see if the thing is null.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
i["serial"].ToString()
```

will probably throw exception if  i["serial"] == null.

The simplest solution would be to just check if it's not null and process it somehow afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your respons @zaaku. var serial = i["serial"].ToString();
                    
                    if(serial == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty serial");
                    }   -  I tried that but it is not working. the array does not continue looping.

Comment: if object - your "i" would have null under "serial" property then extension method .ToString() will throw exception - it's like calling:
    null.ToString();
Check rather i["serial"] == null than i["serial"].ToString() == null

Comment: That i understand. But when i check serial for null: var serial = i["serial"]; It says non is null? @zaaku

Comment: I debugged throught it. var serial = i["serial"]; Debugger says serial value is equel to {}? @zaaku